# Repeat values with a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, repeat

I am dealing with a summarized data set that is similar to the one below, and I need to expand it so that it looks like the second dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(CustName = letters[1:3],
Years = c(4,2,1), 
MinYear = c(1995,1992,1998),
stringsAsFactors = F)

df
```

I have tried to use loops but I've had no success

The desired output is something like this

```
dfResult <- data.frame(CustName = rep(letters[1:3], c(4,2,1)),
Years = c(1995:1998, 1992:1993, 1998), stringsAsFactors = F)

dfResult
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically need to split your dataset by customer name, then create a new dataframe from the data for each customer. We do this by adding 0:(Years-1) to the startyear. The -1 is to account for the start-year. Finally, we bind these together. We can do this in base-R:

```
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$CustName),function(x){
  res <- data.frame(custName=x$CustName,
                    Year=x$MinYear+0:(x$Years-1))
  res
}))

# > res
# custName Year
# a.1        a 1995
# a.2        a 1996
# a.3        a 1997
# a.4        a 1998
# b.1        b 1992
# b.2        b 1993
# c          c 1998
```

We can do the same with data.table, makes the code more readable:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)

res <- DT[,.(Year=MinYear+0:(Years-1)),CustName]
```